# SQL to normalize existing (many-to-many) data

Tags: sql, sqlite, ms-access, many-to-many, normalization

**Summary:**
See below for Details. I'm copying the `[unanswered`] many-to-many question here to the top for readability:

```
    Given the "Input" table, what is the SQL to generate the 3rd "Output"
    table (Person_plays_Instrument)?
```

**Current input (1 table):**

```
OriginalTable:
PersonId PersonName Instrument_1 Instrument_2 Instrument_3 MailingAddress HomePhone
--------|----------|------------|------------|------------|--------------|------------
1        Bob        Violin       Viola        Trumpet      someplace      111-111-1111
2        Suzie      Cello        Flute        <null>       otherplace     222-222-2222
3        Jim        Violin       <null>       <null>       thirdplace     333-333-3333
```

**Desired output (3 tables):**

```
Person:
Id Name   MailingAddress HomePhone
--|------|--------------|------------
1  Bob    someplace      111-111-1111
2  Suzie  otherplace     222-222-2222
3  Jim    thirdplace     333-333-3333

Instrument:
Id Name
--|-------
1  Violin
2  Cello
3  Viola
4  Flute
5  Trumpet

Person_plays_Instrument:
PersonId InstrumentId
--------|------------
1        1
1        3
1        5
2        2
2        4
3        1
```

---

**Details:**

I have a single flat SQL table which started out as a spreadsheet. I'd like to normalize it. I'll split this into 1 question for each table.

Questions 1 and 2 have been answered, but I am leaving them in in case others find them helpful.

**Questions:**

*Question #1*: `[answered`]
How do I generate Person table?

*Answer #1*:
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276737/normalizing-an-existing-ms-access-database/276953#276953) wonderful post gets me 2/3rds of the way there. For the one-to-many tables, I'm set. Here's the code:

```
[add autonumber field to OriginalTable, name it PersonId]
[create empty Person table with Id, Name, MailingAddress, HomePhone fields]

INSERT INTO Person (Id, Name, MailingAddress, HomePhone)
  SELECT o.PersonID, o.PersonName, o.MailingAddress, o.HomePhone
  FROM OriginalTable as o
  WHERE o.PersonName Is Not Null;
```

---

*Question #2*: `[attempted`] (*better version by @Branko in Accepted Answer*)
How do I generate Instrument table?

*Answer #2*:
Again, one-to-many. At first, the multiple columns had me stumped.
The solution came in two parts:

- I'd just have to repeat the INSERT command, once for each column.
- Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/232951/1421642) post and the IN operator, I can check each time to confirm I hadn't already inserted that value.

Here's the code:

```
[create empty Instrument table with Id[autonumber], Name fields]

INSERT INTO Instrument (Name)
  SELECT Distinct o.Instrument_1
  FROM OriginalTable as o
  WHERE o.Instrument_1 Is Not Null
  AND o.Instrument_1 Not In (SELECT Name from Instrument);

INSERT INTO Instrument (Name)
  SELECT Distinct o.Instrument_2
  FROM OriginalTable as o
  WHERE o.Instrument_2 Is Not Null
  AND o.Instrument_2 Not In (SELECT Name from Instrument);

INSERT INTO Instrument (Name)
  SELECT Distinct o.Instrument_3
  FROM OriginalTable as o
  WHERE o.Instrument_3 Is Not Null
  AND o.Instrument_3 Not In (SELECT Name from Instrument);
```

---

*Question #3*: `[unanswered`]
How do I generate Person_plays_Instrument table?

Comment: Is there `OriginalTable.PersonID`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I mentioned it in the "[add autonumber field to OriginalTable, name it PersonId]" bit. I actually intentionally removed it from my example because adding the autonumber field is one of the main steps in the answer post I linked to in Q#1. In retrospect it made things more confusing. I'll edit it in for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is `OriginalTable.PersonID`, which you haven't shown us, but is implied by your own answer #1, the **answer #3** can be expressed simply as:

```
INSERT INTO Person_plays_Instrument (PersonId, InstrumentId)
SELECT PersonID, Instrument.Id
FROM
    OriginalTable
    JOIN Instrument
        ON OriginalTable.Instrument_1 = Instrument.Name
        OR OriginalTable.Instrument_2 = Instrument.Name
        OR OriginalTable.Instrument_3 = Instrument.Name;
```

BTW, there is a more concise way to express the **answer #2**:

```
INSERT INTO Instrument (Name)
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT o.Instrument_1 I
        FROM OriginalTable as o
        UNION
        SELECT o.Instrument_2
        FROM OriginalTable as o
        UNION
        SELECT o.Instrument_3
        FROM OriginalTable as o
    ) Q
    WHERE I IS NOT NULL;
```

And here is a fully working [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26516/13) for MS SQL Server. Other DBMSes should behave similarly. BTW, you should tag your question appropriately to indicate your DBMS.

Comment: I am in awe of this answer. It works exactly as hoped. In addition, the link to SQL Fiddle and the improved code for my Answer #2 are beautiful. Can't thank you enough. Only wish I had more than one upvote button :)

Comment: As a followup: I retagged the way you suggested. I also want to reiterate my thanks for the thoroughness of your SQL Fiddle example. I'm usually a java programmer; still a SQL newbie. I've learned more about SQL from your example in the last 10 minutes than in a week of tutorial sites and googling. Thanks again!

Comment: @Bukov You are most welcome! But I still don't see any tags such as [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle], [tag:postgresql] or [tag:mysql]...

Comment: Ohh, you meant a tag for which *specific* DBMS I was using. At the moment I'm editing in MS Access because I don't have anything better. Eventually, once I've got the schema fixed and the data normalized (using the method you've just helped me with!) I'll be moving everything into SQLite for a Rails project. I'll add Access and SQLite tags to the original question for you :)

Comment: May I 2 questions about your more-concise Answer #2: (a) What is the letter "Q" doing right after the brackets? (b) "Where I Is Not Null" looks like it only applies to Instrument_1. Yet magically we're not getting back nulls even though we include Instrument_2 and _3, which have nulls. How is this happening?

Comment: @Bukov (a) This is just a peculiarity of the MS SQL Server syntax - it requires all subqueries to be named (even though that name is not really used anywhere). Other DBMSes might allow you to omit that.

Comment: @Bukov (b) The WHERE clause exists at the level of the **outer** query, so it applies to all rows returned from the inner query - look at how parenthesis ( and ) are organized. To put it differently: first the inner query UNIONs all rows together, then the outer query filters-out the NULLs from all these rows. You could achieve the same effect by just repeating the WHERE 3 times in the inner query (at which point you could omit the outer query entirely), but why repeat something if you don't have to?

Comment: Thanks again for such helpful answers! I believe understand much better now. (a) Q was just the alias for what was in the brackets. (b) The inner query makes a temporary Table. The table's 1 Column takes it's name from whatever the 1st thing in the Union is. Then the outer table looks at the name you gave that 1 Column and drops out any nulls